# Change version of Visual Studio from 2015 to 2005

Tags: visual-c++, sfml

I use SFML library version2.4 on Visual Studio(VS) 2015. Now, I want to use VS 2005 instead and SMFL(2.4) does not support it. I want to use some functions in SFML(2.4). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any specific reason you're going back?

Besides that, it should most likely work. All you have to do is [compile SFML yourself](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/compile-with-cmake.php) (and possibly the dependencies as well) to get the right files for your version.

Comment: I need to go back because the main program is running on VS2005. Compile SFML yourself is the same thing like compiling with CMake, right?

Comment: @Melo234 Yes, Cmake just organizes the project files for your environment.